# Problema para atacar filho e duvida no uso this

Tags: jquery, html

Estou com problemas para entender o uso do this.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div id="a" class="clsa">
    bbb
</div>

<div id="b" class="clsb">
    <span id="bb" clsbb> Conteudo bb </span>
</div>
```

Queria atacar qualquer um dos elementos no momento da leitura do mesmo. Estou fazendo desta forma e esta funcionando:

```
$("#a").ready(function() {
    //Chamando uma função e passando parametros funcionar normalmente, eu queria poder atacar daqui de dentro este mesmo elemento "#a".
})
```

Agora eu queria poder pegar o span do b seguindo a mesma ideia da anterior e atacar este span:

```
$("#b").ready(function() {
    //Chamar o span e atacar ele (fazer alguma coisa, mudar o texto, colocar uma classe)
})
```

estou tentando com o this, mais não esta rolando. Ele esta chamando o document e não este elemento:

```
$("#b").ready(function() {
    this.text("teste");
})
```

Estou usando o this certo?

Estou fazendo a chamada "$("#a").ready(.." certo?

Estou errando em algum ponto?

Se fosse para atacar ele depois q a pagina fosse carregada é só alterar o ready para load igual $(documento).ready e (window).load?

Me ajudem pf

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres dizer com `atacar`? Explica também o que queres fazer com esse texto para podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: tentou com `$(this)` ao invés de `this`?

Comment: Me parece que atacar significa manipular.

Comment: Em que país se usa esta expressão ``atacar``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando tu for usar o this referente ao elemento que disparou o evento, vai precisar usa-lo como um seletor jquery:

```
$("#a").ready(function(){
      $(this).html("Oii");
      //Onde $(this) = $("#a");
});
```

Essa regra muda quando voce estiver dentro de laços de repetição, por exemplo, quando o $(this) vai referenciar o proprio elemento em leitura:

```
$("#a").ready(function(){
      $.each($("#minhaUl li"), function(index){
            $(this).html("Oii");
            //Onde $(this) = elemento li em leitura;
      });
});
```

O que significa que o this tem valor diferente, de acordo com o contexto de execução.

http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Para manipular os elementos internos ao ouvinte do evento, tem uma série de formas de fazer.

```
$("#b").ready(function() {
    $("#b > span").html("Oii");
    $("#b span").html("Oii");
    $("#b").find("span").html("Oii"); //$(this).find("span").html("Oii");
    ... //e outras
})
```

https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

https://api.jquery.com/children/

https://api.jquery.com/find/

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Mas uma coisa que não entendi é pq você está usando `$(element).ready(...)`, pq se tu só quer atribuir um valor ou algo assim, poderia usar direto no:

`$(document).ready(function(){  $("#b").find("span").html("Oii"); ... });`

Comment: Qual a diferença em usar:

$(element).ready(...)

e

$(document).ready(function(){  $("#b").find("span").html("Oii"); ... });

Comment: Mais uma ultima pergunta. Se eu tiver uma função X e quiser chamar ele no elemento é possivel ( $("#b").x(asdf)  )?

Comment: Bem, eu colocaria dentro do document.ready porque: fica melhor de ler e porque o navegador vai disparar um único evento de ready e tu vai executar td dentro dele. Ao inves de vários outros eventos q fazem todos a mesma coisa. Levando em consideração que tudo que estiver dentro só vai executar uma vez mesmo, seria melhor ter uma única função de ready, não? E quanto a dúvida sobre o método. Se tu quiser chamar qndo executar algo, ex: clicar num botão: $("#btn").click(function() { metodo();});

Comment: Quanto ao ready, muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito. Referente a função, agora funcionara desta forma q você acabou de me explicar 
 (document)... Mais e se eu não estive usando o  (document)... mais sim $("#b").x(asdf), ela não sera disparada por meio de click, mouse, ... e sim quando o elemento for lido $("#b").ready(function() {...}) . Digamos que eu criei uma função com uma ação x, queria poder chamar esta função, é possível? Eu tendo da forma q passei, só q esta dando erro, fala que não exite a função x.

Comment: Não to entendendo bem o que você quer dizer... Quando o elemento for lido vai acontecer o que?

Comment: Eu quero disparar ele sem ser por meio de click, mouse, ... Por exemplo, "    $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});    " se eu clicar vai executar a função hide nativa do jquery, tem como eu executar sem ser por meio de evento click, mouse,..., mais no momento que o arquivo for lido pelo navegador? E no caso, queria poder executar uma função que eu criei "    $("p").x();    "

Comment: Claro, no $(document).ready(function(){  x();  });  Esse método executa o q?

Comment: O que tu quer fazer? Explica certinho. Tu quer que quando abra a página oculte alguma coisa, é isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58213/discussion-between-antoniosantos-and-aline).

Comment: Chat bloqueado aqui. (Y) Imagens bloqueadas... aheuhas tudo que eu puder ajudar é só vendo o que tu tem a mostrar.

Comment: fazendo desta forma $(document).ready(function(){ x(); }); funciona e fica perfeito. 
Agora por questões de duvidas, neste formato: 
    "    
function funcA(parametro) { 
var qualquerCoisa = parametro; 
console.info(qualquerCoisa); 
}    "    "

$("#b").ready(function(){ 
var conteudo = $(this).html(); 

funcA("conteudo"); 
});     "       
tem como isso funcionar?

separei cada instrução com "" para poder distinguir um codigo do outro

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ funcA($("#b").html()); }); Vai funcionar assim. (=

Comment: Funcionou, vlw. É só envolver tudo pela função?!

Comment: Tudo que tu faria: $(element).ready, poe dentro do $(document).ready(..) e vai sair funcionando. $(document).ready(function() {  funcA($("#b").html()); funcB(); x(); y($("#txt").val()); } ...

Comment: Somente um $(document).ready(..) por arquivo neh? Esta e a ultima pergunta. Agradecendo por tudo.

Comment: É o ideal. Nada te impede de declarar varias vezes, mas não é bacana no quesito organização. (= Disponha.

Answer (score 1):

Com Jquery você pode usar `child selector` ( > ) para chegar no span de dentro da div #b.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#b").ready(function() {
    $("#b > span").html("teste");
})
</script>

<div id="b" class="clsb">
    <span id="bb"> Conteudo bb </span>
    <br>outra coisa q vai continuar aqui 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O método $(**document**).ready() será chamadado no momento da construção da página, apenas isso, se tiver algum post com ajax por exemplo no seu código, após a chamada desse método o $(**document**).ready() não será chamado.
Quanto ao segundo ponto que é a utilização do **this** segue exemplo:

```
$("#b").ready(function() {
    // this nesse caso é o objeto #b
    this.text("teste");
})
```

O **this** sempre será o objeto que chamou o método, se você quer utilizar isso no $(**document**).ready() não há necessidade de utilizar dessa maneira acima, exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#bb").text("teste");
})
```

O uso que você deu exemplo acima, é mais em casos de varrer alguma lista ou algo parecido, exemplo:

```
// varre todas as divs da página setando nas spans que estão dentro das divs

$("div").each(function()
{
// this nesse caso é a div atual
  $(this).find("span").css("color","red");
})

$("#bb").click(function()
{
// nesse caso o this é a span #bb
$(this).text("teste");
})
```